# NVIDIA driver 535.129.03 won't load on fedora 39

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

Can someone help me with my fedora 39 workstations. I have Optimus laptops with two dedicated GPU

```
lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D controller" 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620]
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX230] (rev a1)
```

At first I installed nvidia driver via `$sudo dnf install gcc kernel-headers kernel-devel akmod-nvidia xorg-x11-drv-nvidia xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-libs xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-libs.i686 -y` fusion repo but it keep give me message nvidia kernel don't being load up or something like that.
In terminal still give me the above error.

I had disabled secure-boot in my bios and change my grub config `/etc/default/grub`
in case if you gonna ask.

I changed it with this line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb quiet rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau modprobe.blacklist=nouveau nvidia-drm.modeset=1"` and, `dracut --force`.

When I reboot it, still it gives me this `NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.` thing,

so then I remove the previous driver `sudo dnf remove \*nvidia\*` and I tried the manual installation via `NVIDIA**.run` with precarious steps and guess what.

nvidia-settings

> ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
>
> [1]    9507 segmentation fault (core dumped)  nvidia-settings

If someone have any solution I'll be appreciated it.

NOTE:
I don't know why but when NVIDIA not installed my libreoffice lagging when tried to read massive text of one document. but when nvidia installed it smooth as hell and my plybackvideo too are smooth.

for information I have tried all the methods I know in Debian too.
following *debian.wiki* and I tried this method following *fedoraproject.org* documentation

Is my driver are loaded but not being recognized??

Comment: Secure Boot prevents loading unsigned drivers. Either sign the Nvidia drivers manually (preferred method) or disable Secure Boot in UEFI.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta, Thank you for your reply. I have signed the Nvidia kernel module. But when I turn off the secure boot it gives me nvidia.ko not found or something like that